# Section break interrupts multilevel heading list & messes headings collapsing behavior

Tags: microsoft-word, list, linebreaks, chapters, custom-multilevel-lists

Trying to achieve: I am trying to include all selected headings in [image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEV7L.png) as subheadings of the "5.3. Technical flow" heading - basically the numbering should change and the collapsing should work (i.e. when I collapse heading 5.3. all subheading should disappear, because they have been collapsed)

Issue: When I collapse all the headings in my document, you can notice in [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLLsq.png) that  this is problematic. I think this is because of the two pages in [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZEa3.png) containing some images, because these have the two-column format.

How could I achieve what I wish? I checked [this](https://superuser.com/questions/566933/heading-2-is-not-followed-by-heading-1-in-microsoft-word-2010-multilevel-heading) thread and asked much the [same question a couple of days ago](https://superuser.com/questions/1724186/heading-3-not-seen-as-subheading-of-heading-2), but they didn't really help.

Comment: Please follow up in your original question - https://superuser.com/questions/1724186/heading-3-not-seen-as-subheading-of-heading-2 rather than posting a new question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heading 3 not seen as subheading of heading 2](https://superuser.com/questions/1724186/heading-3-not-seen-as-subheading-of-heading-2)